# Registering custom oracle

Tags: corda

I've followed the oracle example in the corda docs to set up a simple price oracle for our cordapp, but am having an issue when it comes to registering this oracles service within our cordapp.

The error being displayed within our main code is

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Corda service com.secLendModel.flow.oracle.Oracle does not exist

By following this error down the line, it appears that this is because in the constructor of our oracle, the code segment below throws a null pointer exception, although the service seems to exist within our main testing code (i.e when I print the oracles advertised services, com.secLendModel.flow.oracle.Oracle is the only service it advertises)

```
constructor(services: PluginServiceHub) : this(services.myInfo.serviceIdentities(PriceType.type).first(), services)
```

The error for this constructor code is shown within node startup

```
W 09:45:34 1 Node.invoke - com.secLendModel.flow.oracle.Oracle does not have a type field, optimistically proceeding with install.
E 09:45:34 1 Node.installCordaServices - Corda service com.secLendModel.flow.oracle.Oracle failed to instantiate
java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.
at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.first(_Collections.kt:178) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
at com.secLendModel.flow.oracle.Oracle.<init>(Oracle.kt:24) ~[main/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.installCordaService(AbstractNode.kt:322) ~[corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.installCordaServices(AbstractNode.kt:302) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.access$installCordaServices(AbstractNode.kt:99) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$3.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:254) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$3.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:99) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$3.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:597) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$3.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:99) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.inTopLevelTransaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:69) [exposed-0.5.0.jar:?]
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:57) [exposed-0.5.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.utilities.DatabaseSupportKt.transaction(DatabaseSupport.kt:48) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.initialiseDatabasePersistence(AbstractNode.kt:596) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.internal.Node.initialiseDatabasePersistence(Node.kt:304) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:223) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.internal.Node.start(Node.kt:310) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.startNode(NodeStartup.kt:103) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.run(NodeStartup.kt:81) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:11) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
```

It appears this node setup happens within the abstractNode class under install corda service. I am not sure if this could be an error here, an issue with the fact the PluginServiceHub is now depreceated or if I am missing a step in my node setup.

The code used to setup the node is as follows

```
val oracle = startNode(ORACLE, advertisedServices = setOf(ServiceInfo(PriceType.type)))
oracleNode = oracle.get()
//This is what is reporting as empty when instantiating the node, but its definetely not. Could be something to do with abstractNode
println(oracleNode.nodeInfo.serviceIdentities(PriceType.type).first())
setUpNodes()
```

It should be noted that once all the nodes are setup, the oracle node then displays no services

> CN=Oracle SP,O=Oracle SP,L=Brisbane,C=AU started on localhost:20018

While our notary node does display services

> CN=Notary Service,O=R3,OU=corda,L=Zurich,C=CH,OU=corda.notary.validating started on localhost:20009

The code for our oracle follows the example code, and it doesnt seem there is any issues with it but I can post if if need be.

Comment: instead of`services.myInfo.serviceIdentities(PriceType.type).first()`, try first testing to see if there is anything in the collection

Comment: @Les When the constructor is called the collection doesnt contain any PriceType.type service types, which is the main issue im trying to fix (sorry if this wasnt clear). As far as I understand, I registered that type as a service for the oracle node, so the collection shouldn't be empty.

Comment: Have you added your oracle as an advertised service under the deployNodes task in build.gradle?

e.g.
 node {
        name "CN=NodeD,O=NodeD,L=New York,C=US"
        advertisedServices = ["net.corda.yourapp.name_of_oracle_service"]
        p2pPort 10014
        rpcPort 10015
        webPort 10016
        cordapps = []
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": []]]
    }

Answer (score 0):

This is from an older version of Corda that had the concept of service identities for services such as oracles.

The error message indicates that an exception is being thrown on this line:

```
`println(oracleNode.nodeInfo.serviceIdentities(PriceType.type).first())`
```

In particular, it indicates that you are trying to get the first item from a list with no elements, and therefore that the `PriceType.type` service identity has not been registered correctly.

You have probably failed to register the service identity in the node's `node.conf` file.